# tvOS - strange touchesCancelled received

Tags: sprite-kit, tvos

I am having a user input issue in my tvOS SpriteKit project - if I try to move the finger quickly after touching the touchpad on the tv remote I do have touchesCancelled called while if I wait a little while (1s) after first touch (wihout releasing my finger) all works like charm and I can use this tiny interface for steering in my game.

Unfortunately there is no specific code I can paste.

this guy:

```
 override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) { ... }
```

is being called by the system in case a quick finger move but not called if I wait for 1-2 seconds before I start moving my finger.

Any idea what I could have done wrong?

Answer (score 3):

ah .... UISwipeGestureRecognizer from previous Scene was hanging around :(

```
func removeAllGestureRecognizers(){
    for recognizer in self.view!.gestureRecognizers!{
        self.view!.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer);
    }
}
```

fixed my issue ...